# "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" on Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to cloud functions and learning how to send email when documents are created through a trigger in Firestore. I'm following this [tutorial](https://softauthor.com/firebase-functions-send-email/) and i managed to get the email sent but there is an error that i get from cloud functions logs.

The error:

```
{
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "message": "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"
}
```

The function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

admin.initializeApp();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.REACT_HOST,
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.REACT_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});

exports.ProfileCreationEmail = functions.firestore
  .document(`profiles/{profile}`)
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: ` "Heita Admin" ${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
      to: `${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
      subject: `New Professional Profile Signup`,
      html: `<h1>New Profile Created</h1>
                                <p>
                                   <b>User Name: </b>${snap.data().userName}<br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                   <b>Email: </b>${snap.data().email}<br>
                                </p>
                                `,
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error from sending mail: ", error);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Profile Creation Sent!");
    });
  });
```

1. What are the consequences of this error?
2. How do i return a promise or a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Promise version of the `sendMail()` method and adapt your code as follows (using `async`/`await`, as below, or `then()` as well as using `try`/`catch` blocks):

```js
exports.ProfileCreationEmail = functions.firestore
  .document(`profiles/{profile}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: ` "Heita Admin" ${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
        to: `${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
        subject: `New Professional Profile Signup`,
        html: `<h1>New Profile Created</h1>
                              <p>
                                 <b>User Name: </b>${snap.data().userName}<br>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                 <b>Email: </b>${snap.data().email}<br>
                              </p>
                              `,
      };

      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log("Profile Creation Sent!");
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error from sending mail: ", error);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

---

For your question "What are the consequences of this error?" you'll find some details in this [section of the documentation on Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), which explains why you should use Promises in order to manage the lifecycle of your Cloud Function which executes an asynchronous operation (i.e. the `sendMail()` method).